# Get SSL certificate details

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, signature, fingerprint

I want to examine the SSL certificate that `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` receives and I have the following snippet which gives me the Issuer Common Name, and the DER.

```
SecTrustRef trustRef = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
SecTrustEvaluate(trustRef, NULL);
CFIndex count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trustRef); 

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    SecCertificateRef certRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trustRef, i);
    CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certRef);
    CFDataRef certData = SecCertificateCopyData(certRef);
}
```

In addition I would like to get the fingerprint and the signature.
My SSL knowledge isn't that deep; can I perhaps extract the above from the DER representation?

The documentation doesn't help. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html.

Comment: I'm surprised they don't provide tools for working with the DER representation (see also “ASN.1” and “X.509”) as it's really quite complex if you're not doing this on a regular basis.

Comment: I was surprised to find that such vital information weren't available through Cocoa and I had to "go deeper" and use CF…
I will look what I can extract from the DER; complex or not it has to be done...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can obtain the sha1 fingerprint like this.

```
// #import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
+(NSString*)sha1:(NSData*)certData {
    unsigned char sha1Buffer[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH]; 
    CC_SHA1(certData.bytes, certData.length, sha1Buffer); 
    NSMutableString *fingerprint = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 3]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) 
        [fingerprint appendFormat:@"%02x ",sha1Buffer[i]]; 
    return [fingerprint stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]; 
}
```

The md5 fingerprint can be obtained in a similar manner. The sha1 and md5 hashes obtained this way match the fingerprints displayed by Safari and Chrome for an untrusted certificate.

Comment: Is there any way to fetch certificate's start and expiry date. If yes then please share code. Thanks in advance.